# NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

i get this

```
    irb(main):001:0> Match.create(id: 401381886)
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Match Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "matches" WHERE "matches"."id" = 401381886 LI
MIT 1
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4294967295
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 105382029
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:33:in `write_attribute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:70:in `write_attribute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:19:in `__temp__57375627f59646='
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/attribute_methods.rb:126:in `method_missing'
        from W:/projects/rails/private/dota2monster/app/models/match_performance.rb:13:in
`block in getData'
        from W:/projects/rails/private/dota2monster/app/models/match_performance.rb:11:in
`each'
        from W:/projects/rails/private/dota2monster/app/models/match_performance.rb:11:in
`getData'
        from W:/projects/rails/private/dota2monster/app/models/match_performance.rb:7:in `
initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/persistence.rb:36:in `create'
        from W:/projects/rails/private/dota2monster/app/models/match.rb:25:in `getData'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/
active_support/callbacks.rb:387:in `_run__512386826__save__callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/
active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
... 3 levels...
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transact
ion'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transa
ction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/a
ctive_record/persistence.rb:37:in `create'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails
/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails
/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails
/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Match Model

```
    class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    include HTTParty

    has_many :matchperformances
    has_many :users, through: :matchperformances

    before_save :getData

    validates :id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    def response(api_id)
        base_url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?key=5F45B214200C4274114FE87E3A62E7B8&match_id="
        url = base_url + api_id.to_s
        response = HTTParty.get(url)
    end
    def getData
        response = response(self.id)
        match = response["result"]
        self.radiant_win = match["radiant_win"]
        self.duration = match["duration"]
        self.start_time = match["start_time"]
        self.lobby_type = match["lobby_type"]
        self.human_players = match["human_players"]
        self.leagueid = match["leagueid"]
        self.game_mode = match["game_mode"]
        MatchPerformance.create(response)
    end
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :match_performances
    has_many :matches, through: :match_performances
end
```

MatchPerformance Model

```
class MatchPerformance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :match

    def initialize(response)
        @response = response
        getData(@response)
    end

    def getData(response)
        response["result"]["players"].each do |player|
            unless User.where(id: player["account_id"]).blank?              
                self.user_id = player["account_id"]
                self.match_id = response["result"]["match_id"]
                self.player_slot = player["player_slot"]
                self.hero_id = player["hero_id"]
                self.item_0 = player["item_0"]
                self.item_1 = player["item_1"]
                self.item_2 = player["item_2"]
                self.item_3 = player["item_3"]
                self.item_4 = player["item_4"]
                self.item_5 = player["item_5"]
                self.kills = player["kills"]
                self.deaths = player["deaths"]
                self.assits = player["assits"]
                self.leaver_status = player["leaver_status"]
                self.gold = player["gold"]
                self.last_hits = player["last_hits"]
                self.denies = player["denies"]
                self.gold_per_min = player["gold_per_min"]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I try to make a dota2 api.
When a user gives the match id, it gets the data from the api, and stores it in the db, so i don't need to bash their api

i think the problem is with

```
def initialize(response)
        @response = response
        getData(@response)
    end
```

Comment: You should provide more of the stacktrace - at least down to where it points to your code, and then make sure you're including the code in question. You're basically asking why your code is generating this error, but not providing the call history.

Comment: This probably won't help much, but you're failing because `@attributes_cache` is `nil` in ActiveRecord, which it shouldn't be.  Google "activerecord @attributes_cache nil" shows some similar questions, but unfortunately no obvious answers.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
def initialize(response)
  super
  @response = response
  getData(@response)
end
```

According to this blog post [Rails: Don't override initialize on ActiveRecord objects](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html) You shouldn't rely on this method for ActiveRecord objects.